# iPython + pylab/matplotlib animations hang

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ipython

I cannot for the life of me get iPython to show an animated plot. This code is taken directly from the matplotlib animation examples, and it works fine using plain old python (aka `python animate.py`).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

def update(data):
    line.set_ydata(data)
    return line,

def data_gen():
    while True: yield np.random.rand(10)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, interval=100)

#plt.ion()
plt.show()

#while 1:
    #plt.draw()
```

calling with `ipython --pylab auto animate.py`, `ipython --pylab tk animate.py` both cause the window to disappear immediately. If I uncomment the `ion()` and `plt.draw()` it just draws a single frame and then hangs. I need to use iPython because it is much more thread-safe than the normal matplotlib implementation.

What am I doing wrong? Using python2.7.2 on osx 10.8 with iPython 1.1 and matplotlib 1.3

Answer (score 1):

The above - without uncommenting anythin works fine with just:

```
ipython animate.py
```

So does

```
ipython --pylab=auto

In [1]: import animate
```

So I think that your problem is that you are trying to combine interactive mode where the backend selection is important with a script that runs continuously with no interaction - this is a conflict.

Reading the documents [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#matplotlib-support) and [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.inputhook.html#module-IPython.lib.inputhook) I suspect you need to make a call to `IPython.lib.inputhook.InputHookManager` in `animate.py` to set your backend.

IPython 0.13.2 matplotlib '1.3.0' kubuntu 13.10

Comment: Hi Steve, if you don't use the --pylab switch then it doesn't activate the ipython backend that I am interested in using (afaik anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I too have been trying this. It seems the majority of users use JSAnimation from Jake Vanderplaas. Link. https://github.com/jakevdp/JSAnimation. This is not a package in the Enthought distribution, however, which then presents the need to import separately.