# Visualizing data with matplotlib

Tags: python, matlab, animation, matplotlib

In Matlab, you can use [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) to view a calculation's result while it's in progress. I have tried a similar syntax in Python, both with matplotlib and mayavi.

I know it's possible to [animate in one dimension](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations#head-e50abcca4333d3d76b3f2bb66ef00f15c6b4dbbc) with `ion` and `set_data`. However, animating in two dimensions (via imshow) is useful and I couldn't find an *easy* way to do that.

I know it's possible to [animate using a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743673/show-consecutive-images-arrays-with-imshow-as-repeating-animation-in-python) but that's not as useful for algorithm development (since you can't use IPython's `%run` and query your program).

In matplotlib, I can use

```
N = 16
first_image = arange(N*N).reshape(N,N)
myobj = imshow(first_image)
for i in arange(N*N):
    first_image.flat[i] = 0
    myobj.set_data(first_image)
    draw()
```

to animate an image but this script doesn't respond to `<Cntrl-C>` -- it hangs and disables  future animations (on this machine). Despite [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466825/ipython-pylab-matplotlib-animations-hang), different ways of invoking this animation process does not work. How do I view 2D data as it's being calculated?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I have since made a package called [python-drawnow](https://github.com/scottsievert/python-drawnow) to implement the following answer.

You just want to visualize the data from some complicated computation and not smoothly animate an image, correct? Then you can just define some simple functions:

```
def drawnow(draw_fig, wait_secs=1):
    """
        draw_fig: (callable, no args by use of python's global scope) your
        function to draw the figure. it should include the figure() call --
        just like you'd normally do it.  However, you must leave out the
        show().

        wait_secs : optional, how many seconds to wait. note that if this is 0
        and your computation is fast, you don't really see the plot update.

        does not work in ipy-qt. only works in the ipython shell.
    """
    close()
    draw_fig()
    draw()
    time.sleep(wait_secs)

def drawnow_init():
    ion()
```

An example of this:

```
def draw_fig():
    figure()
    imshow(z, interpolation='nearest')
    #show()

N = 16
x = linspace(-1, 1, num=N)
x, y = meshgrid(x, x)
z = x**2 + y**2


drawnow_init()
for i in arange(2*N):
    z.flat[i] = 0
    drawnow(draw_fig)
```

Notice this requires that the variables you're plotting be global. This shouldn't be a problem since it seems that the variables you want to visualize are global.

This method responds fine to cntrl-c and is visible even during fast computations (through `wait_secs`.